# Why is Windows 10 not letting me set my Windows Admin USER name?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, microsoft-account

when I reset my Windows 10, when I open cmd, the user path shown there is 
C: \Users\nitis> 
however my name is Nitish and I want that to be shown and windows 10 nowhere asked me to set my user name. 
I created a new Microsoft account for this but to no avail, cause everytime it uses first 5 characters of name

when I tried to reset windows 10 using previous Microsoft account... it used first 5 characters of my last name.

please help me what to do

Comment: Unfortunately truncating the name to five characters is a 'feature' of using a Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I found a workaround.

The thing is that if you sign-in using Microsoft account, then it by default truncates to 5 characters of your email. 
so you must sign-in using a local account first and then assign a username and then change it to Microsoft account. 
but sometimes it windows doesn't let you to create a local account at start. for this follow below steps.

for all those who have reset their PC into totally new windows, and want the username of their choice... one way to achieve this is by doing following :

1. if Microsoft initially is not letting you set local account and instead wants you to login using Microsoft account, then first sign-in using Microsoft account (let's call this account M)
2. now after done, from inside M create a new local account of your username choice (call this account X)
3. now make it(X) admin
4. now signout of your initially signed in microsoft account (M)
5. now sign-in through the local account you created (X)
6. and from X delete M

done! you have your account of your username choice